# Power Bi publish only one line

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I created a table in Power Bi desktop that has more than a thousand rows, the publication took place the way I would like. For some reason still unknown, after a few days this publication displays only one row (in the desktop version It Works perfectly). I tried changing the security part at the line level but so far nothing has worked, any suggestions?

My expectation would be to display all lines in the published version.